# how to change a variable name in a while loop?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a question. I want to use a while loop and in the while loop I have to assign a view lists, but they shouldn't be assigned to the same variable over and over again. but I don't know how much lists I have to assign.

```
K = 2
D = 2
while( K <= 2 or K >= 20):
    K = int(raw_input("Give the number of candidates running for speaker. "))
    if(K <= 2 or K >= 20):
        print("Sorry, wrong input.")

while(D <= 2 or D >= 1000):
    D = int(raw_input("Give the number of people who take part in the meeting. "))
    if(D <= 2 or D >= 1000):
        print("Sorry, wrong input.")

row = 1
vlist = [[]*D]
while(D > row):
    while(K < len(vlist[row-1])):
        number = int(raw_input("Give a number of a person you want to win: "))
        if(0 < number < K and number not in vlist[row-1]): 
            vlist[row-1].append(number)
        else:
            print("Sorry, wrong input, try again.")

    row += 1
```

this is what I have now, but it throws the following error: List index out of range. I don't get why...

Comment: why `they shouldn't be assigned to the same variable over and over again`?

Comment: because I need to have all the lists separated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

First item of list is empty: `len(vlist[0])`
returns `0`, so `list[row-1]` is trying to acces element of `-1` index.